# How do I solve the stackoverflow problem? BeanSerializer error

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, lombok

I want to start a relationship but I get an error that I can't understand.

Person.java

```java
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Personal implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private String personName;
    private String personLastName;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Address address;
}
```

Address.java

```java
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class Address implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "Street")
    private String street;
    @Column(name = "Alley")
    private String alley;
    @Column(name = "District")
    private String district;


    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "address")
    @MapsId
    private Person person;

    
    public Address(String street, String alley, String district, Person person) {
        this.street = street;
        this.alley = alley;
        this.district = district;
        this.person = person; 
    }
}
```

AddressService.java

```java
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AddressServices {


    private final AddressRepository addressRepository;


    public Optional<Address> getAddress(Integer id){
        return addressRepository.findById(id);
    }
}
```

```java
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class PersonService {

    private final PersonRepository personRepository;


    public String createUser(){
        Person u1 = new Person();
        u1.setId(u1.getId());
        u1.setUserName("test");
        u1.setUserLastName("test");
        Address address = new Address();
        address.setAlley("test");
        address.setDistrict("test");
        address.setStreet("test");
        address.setPerson(u1);
        u1.setAddress(address);
        personRepository.save(u1);
        return "Save is successful";
    }
```

Data is successfully saved in the database. However, when I run "localhost:8080/gget-address?id=1" via postman, I get an error.

ERROR :

```java
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.putVal(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1012) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.putIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1541) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.getClassLoadingLock(ClassLoader.java:667) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:591) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:579) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) ~[na:na]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:774) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.4.2.jar:2.13.4.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.4.2.jar:2.13.4.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:728) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.4.2.jar:2.13.4.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:774) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.4.2.jar:2.13.4.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.4.2.jar:2.13.4.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:728) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.4.2.jar:2.13.4.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:774) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.4.2.jar:2.13.4.2]
```

However, I still have the same problem! :) nothing has changed. the record to the database is successful, but it continues to give the same error when I want to retrieve the data

Before asking this question, I searched for similar questions but I could not find any answer to my problem.

I tried notations such as ***@JsonIgnore, @JsonBackReference, @JsonManagamedReference***, but when I add them, this time the relationship is not established (lombok ignores) my goal is to establish the relationship mutually.  I wonder if "Lombok" is making a mistake.  I'm using Lombok. ?

***What I want is that when I run "localhost:8080/gget-address?id=1", I can see all "person" with address 1.***

There is a problem when using OneToOne and mappedBy.
There is an infinite loop like ***Person-> Address --> Person --> Address.***

I think it falls into serialization error for this reason. I need to solve this. However, I cannot realize what I want in the use of annotation such as **@JsonIgnore, @JsonBackReference, @JsonManagamedReference.** ***When I add them, the "field" is invisible and when I go to address 1, I cannot see the "people" who use address 1.***

---

EDIT AND CREATE DTO / MAPPER

I created DTO objects and mapper classes.

PersonDTO

```java
@Data
public class PersonDTO implements Serializable {
    private String userName;
    private String userLastName;
}
```

AddressDTO

```java
@Data
public class AddressDTO implements Serializable {
    private String street;
    private String alley;
    private String district;
    private PersonDTO personDTO;
}
```

AddressMapper

```java
@Mapper
public interface AddressMapper {
    AddressMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(AddressMapper.class);
    Address addressDtoToAddress(AddressDTO addressDTO);
    AddressDTO addressToAddressDto(Address address);
}
```

PersonMapper

```java
@Mapper
public interface PersonMapper {
    PersonMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(PersonMapper.class);
    Person personDtoToPerson(PersonDTO personDTO);
    PersonDTO personToPersonDTO(Person person);
}
```

After that I send a request to the API.

```json
{
    "street":"test",
    "alley":"test",
    "district":"test",
    "personDTO" : {
        "userName": "test",
        "userLastName": "test"
    }
}
```

and the API gives me this kind of feedback.

```json
{
    "street": "test",
    "alley": "test",
    "district": "test",
    "personDTO": null
}
```

---

API CALL for Address

Then I call the address with id == 1
localhost:8080/get-adress?id=1

```json
{
    "id": 1,
    "street": "test",
    "alley": "test",
    "district": "test",
    "person": null
}
```

---

API CALL for Person

Then I call the Person with id == 1
localhost:8080/get-user?id=1

Response JSON

```json
{
    "id": 1,
    "userName": "test",
    "userLastName": "test",
    "address": null
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You didn't include the `Person` class in your post.  Assuming it is the same as the `Personal` class that you've included, it's likely a circular reference between `Person` and `Address`.

A `Person` has an `Address` which has a `Person` which has an `Address`, etc.

You can solve this by either using @JsonManagedReference and @JsonBackReference, or by adding @JsonIgnore.

In your `Address` class, adding @JsonIgnore to the person will likely fix this issue.

Comment: First of all, thank you for replying! :) When I do @JsonIgnore, it ignores the 'person' object when adding. 

When I want to bring the addresses via Postman, I cannot see the users connected to the addresses, only the addresses come. Do I need to write SQL using "join" for this?  

```json 
{
    "id": 1,
    "street": "test",
    "alley": "test",
    "district": "test"
}
```

However, I want to include in this JSON result the "persons" that use address 1.

Answer (score 1):

It is very bad pratice to return the entity object directly in controller. You should map this to simple dto before. When you want get object from the controller object mapper is trying to serialize address it also serialize person (because it is class member) entity that has n adresses that would be also serialized and then serialize n persons that have n addresses etc. There is a recursion that overflow the stack.

It would looks something like:

```
address: {
properies....
person: {
   properties...
   address: [
   {
      properies....
      person {... address: ...}
   },
   {
      properies....
      person {... address: ...}
   },
   {
      properies....
      person {... address: ...}
   }
   ...
}]}}
```

Imo the best way and practive is creating simple dto like that:

```java
public class AddressDto implements Serializable {

    private Integer id;
    private String street;
    private String alley;
    private String district;
    private PersonDto person;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your valuable comment :) but there is one point that sticks in my mind here. 

As you said, I created the DTO classes and tried to save the data. However, the person class is waiting for an Address. Likewise AddressDTO is waiting for a person. 

They all work but the ID parts remain "null"... how can I overcome this?

Comment: Are you sure that you map object after persisting (after id was obtained from sequence)? Most probably you use one without id. If this does not solve you problem attach some code please.

Comment: Dear @Osker I made additions related to DTO and changes. You can see all the codes above... 

---

OneToOne I want to remind you again that I am trying to build a relationship. To see all users who have registered at address 1.

Comment: As I see you are using mapstruct. I dont like libraries like that. But looking your code in 'Address' class you have property: 'private Person person;' and 'AddressDto' has 'private PersonDTO personDTO;' how this mapper will know how to map this correctly
even if the variable names don't match. Try to write simple mapper cuz there is probably a mistake.

Comment: So I need to match 'private Person person' in the 'Address' entity with 'private PersonDTO personDto' in the DTO? Do I understand correctly?

Comment: Your mapper is returning null for field: 'private PersonDTO personDto'. There are actually only 2 ways why it may happen. 1: Person is null and it is mapping to null correctly. 2: Your mapper from mapstruct does not work. But IMO there is no way to work.

How this method 'PersonDTO personToPersonDTO(Person person);' is supposted to know that field person should be mapped to personDTO.

First try to write own implementation of mapper. Just simple method like: public static AddressDto mapToAddressDto(Address address) {
implementation....
}

Comment: When I add an address in this way, 1 user is automatically added. 

I do not want a user to be added every time an address is added. 

I want to be able to address users. When I do DTO and matching, it automatically adds 1 user every time I add an address. I do not want this.

Comment: I created a user named "test". I want to give the address information when creating it. I have addresses in the database. I saved the address of the user named "test" as address number 1. Then I created a user named "test2". and I saved its address as address number "1". 

When I say getAddressFindById(1), I want to bring all users (new test and test2) that are registered to number 1.

Comment: I did not say anything about changing way in address saving id db. Just change mapping to your dto cuz it probably does not work or write unit test for that. Cuz Im 100% procent sure that it must not work.

Comment: every time I register an address it automatically registers a user. I think I am completely confused haha :) thanks for your help.